# R package: Write own summary function (method)

Tags: r, package, summary, cran

I wrote an R package which fits a statistical model, say of class `class`. I want to write my own summary method `summary.class` in the style of `summary.lm`.

I am confused how to produce such a summary output. My model of class `class` is a list which, e.g., contains the element `pvalue = 0.05`. Do I use `cat` in `summary.class` to print the p-value? How to properly format multiple outputs of this kind in a table?

`summary.lm` does not seem to contain any `print` or `cat` command.

```r
summary.class = function(obj,...){
  cat(obj$pvalue)
}
```

Comment: Maybe you find what I did for `fastLm()` useful: https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/R/fastLm.R#L49-L110

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical approach when writing summary functions is to gather all the info you want, create an object with all of that information, give that object a new class (probably something like summary.yourclass), and then return the object.  Ultimately you would then need to write a new function that does print.summary.yourclass.  Inside of that print function you probably would make some calls to cat or something similar.